# Once I set up AppleTV to to play My Photo stream photos, can it update the photo stream automatically (or even manually)?

Tags: appletv

I have an Apple TV 2 that I set up to use a screen Saver of My Photo Stream ( Settings > Screen Saver > Photos > My Photo stream )

it appears to have imported what it claims are 379 photos from my Apple photo stream on the day I set it up -- 11/16. However, it does not seem to *update* the photos ever, even though the device is connected to the internet.

when I go to the settings, I can see the photo stream from that date

[image]

is it possible to have the apple TV continually update my photo stream? And/or it is possible to update it manually myself. I don't see a way to even update it manually myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some strange reason as I was going to ask this question the Apple TV photo stream updated itself and it now says "Today 4:57 PM" with 374 photos

I don't really have an explanation other than I went to the settings and click in it & back maybe once or twice.